# jQuery - setTimeout does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

There is my script: https://jsfiddle.net/hcsofjaa/1/
I want to change color of these cells every 2000ms one by one, but It seems the setTimeout function does not work properly. Does anybody know, where is the problem?

```
$("#button").click(function(){
for (var i = $("span").length; i > 0; i--) {

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("span:nth-child("+i+")").css("background-color","blue");
    }, 2000);

}
```

Comment: `i` isn't what you think it is when the timeout fires. The linked question's answers explain why and how to fix it.

Comment: Definitely not setTimeout's problem. Either you're not looping correctly or your css application isn't correct.

Comment: *"X doesn't work"* is almost never a good question

Comment: @UsopleskCz: Try the answer

Comment: answer improved

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: As per my understanding question is not duplicate. It looks like he is a learner, not able to achieve the functionality he is looking for.

Can you double check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) **$(function)** is important - bind click event to element after it rendered.

2) **2000 * i** : button colors change in the gap of 2000

```
$(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
  $("span").each(function(i){
   var e = this;
   setTimeout(function(){
     $(e).css("background-color","blue");
   }, 2000 * i);
   });     
   });
});
```

Comment: Peoples putting down vote. If they given reason in comments. It will correct my mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it now.

Comment: @UsopleskCz: Welcome:)